# wordpress get_post_meta refers to local link only

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce

I am trying to build a page with links to developer websites. I use woocommerce to display products and custom fields for developer website links. All is done except the fact links obtained from custom field always refers to local website.
For example: I have **www.developerpage.com** as a link, but  links to **localhost/mypage/www.developerpage.com** (xampp) instead of www.developerpage.com

To display value from text of custom field I use following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_urltextinput", true); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">My link</a>
```

I am really beginner therefore I don't know what is wrong with this line.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `http://` in front of your link.